# Column has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, columnstore

I want to create a clustered columnstore index in a table using the following query:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci
ON agl_20180319_bck
```

And I am getting this error:

> Msg 35343, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> The statement failed. Column 'memberOf' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index. Omit column 'memberOf'.

The 'memberOf' is in this type: `memberOf nvarchar(max)`.

How to overcome/ignore this error and what does it mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql):

> Columns that use any of the following data types cannot be included in
> a columnstore index:
>
> nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) (Applies to SQL Server
> 2016 and prior versions, and nonclustered columnstore indexes)

Either change the type of the column (if you can) or just don't have a columnstore index on this specific column.

Comment: Than means that i have to create a nonclustered columnstore index?

Comment: No, it means you can't create a columnstore index on that column at all. You could try to change the type from nvarchar(max) to limit it, for example set the length to 4000. Then you can create a columnstore index on it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to specify the participating columns individually, excluding memberOf and any other columns that can't be used in a columnStore index

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I got the message: _The statement failed because specifying a key list is not allowed when creating a clustered columnstore index. Create the clustered columnstore index without specifying a key list._

Comment: `CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cci
ON algtable_20180319_bck (displayname, alias,
firstname, lastname, exaddress)`

Answer (score 2):

just specify the length of the varchar variables instead of using max. Did the trick for me!